# SUM not display correct sum MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query:

```
SELECT sum(TIMEDIFF(`time_out`, `time_in`)) as `total` FROM `user_log` WHERE `uid` = '1' AND `time_out` <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

Then I calculate the seconds to hours:

```
$total_difference = (($difference->total) / 60 / 60);
```

But this is showing me 22,352125 hours, which is impossible...

I've been testing and I have 2 records showing up **if I don't use SUM**:

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF(`time_out`, `time_in`) as `total` FROM `user_log` WHERE `uid` = '1' AND `time_out` <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

1. 08:00:02
2. 00:00:11

This result is far below the 22 hours I get when I use SUM in my query. Any help? I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: $total_difference = (($difference->total) / 3600); try this

Comment: try `SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(`time_out`, `time_in`)))`

Comment: @anant kumar singh: It's still the same result. :\

Comment: @amdixon: It looks like that did the job. Thanks!

Comment: @amdixon, I believe you should write it as an answer since it solved the problem

Comment: SUM(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time_out) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time_in))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can adjust the query to use [TIME_TO_SEC](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-time_to_sec-function.php) - this will convert the return value of [TIMEDIFF](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-timediff-function.php) to a numeric number of seconds, which can sensibly be summed

**adjusted query**

```
SELECT SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(time_out, time_in))) as total 
FROM user_log 
WHERE uid = '1' AND time_out <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
;
```